# Sample mic input on mac in Swift

Tags: macos, swift, audio, avfoundation, microphone

I know getting microphone input has been asked many types before, but only for iOS. The Apple docs about AVFoundation only talk about iOS, so I'm not sure if it's even meant to be used on a mac. I have looked at CoreAudio, and most of it is deprecated, and the only docs are in Objective-C. I am looking for a standard-lib swift solution of getting microphone samples. Does anybody have anything or is this type of stuff just not done in swift?

Comment: AVFoundation is (very almost) the same on OSX as on iOS, so you can ude pretty much any AVFoundation Tutorial

Comment: @Kametrixom Unfortunately, exactly the class I need (AVAudioSession) does not exist for OS X ! It only exists for iOS. Do you know an alternative?

Comment: Yeah you can use AVCaptureSession :)